# UITableView shows no scroll Indicators when added as a Subview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

i have a View Controller to which i added a tableview as a Subview via Interface Builder. Everything works fine but strangely there is no Scroll Indicator. Even when I enable the Scroll Indicator via Code with(_miniTableView is a strong Outlet)

```
_miniTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;  
[_miniTableView flashScrollIndicators];
```

there is no Scroll Indicator Appearing.
Moving the the Scroll Indicator via an Inset also does nothing

```
_miniTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,7);
```

(everything is called in viewWillAppear)

You can replicate the bug by creating a simple application and adding a tableview as a subview(not via a container view) via interface builder and there will be no scroll indicator.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Two possibilities I can think of:  (1) `_miniTableView` doesn't actually point to your table view, and (2) your table view's frame is set outside the bounds of its superview (ie, the scroll indicators are appearing, but off-screen)

Comment: (1) not possible because i setup things with this reference and these things work (2) wouldn't setting the scrollIndicatorInsets move the Scroll inside the viewable frame?

Comment: try just setting your scroll view frame to its parent view's bounds and see if it shows up. just to test that hypothesis.

Comment: You can also set scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 and visually inspect the frame of your scrollView, etc.

Comment: Also consider using SparkInspector, you do not need to make any changes to your project, free trial. This helped me in similar situations.

Comment: you mean via `[_miniTableView setFrame:self.view.bounds]` ? tried that does not even resize the table view. also the layer.borderWidth is already in the Code and the frame of the table view seems okay. you can btw replicate the bug by creating a new project and adding a tableview as a subview. there will be no scroll indicator.

Comment: You are right--the tableview will not show the scroll indicators unless it has content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the table view will not show a scroll indicator unless it is scrollable.

I verified it with the following code... (just an empty project with an app delegate modified as shown)

```
@interface AppDelegate()<UITableViewDataSource>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UITableView * tableView = [ [ UITableView alloc ] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds ] ;
    [self.window addSubview:tableView ] ;

    tableView.dataSource = self ;

    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30 ; // setting this to 0 results in an empty table view with no scroll indicators...
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" ] ;
    if ( !cell )
    {
        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc ] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell" ] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row ] ;
    return cell ;
}
@end
```

Comment: that is in fact the reason why! thanks for that. do you think there is a way to force the uitableview to show a scroll indcator?

Comment: perhaps not.. but if there's no scrolling necessary (and you can see the cells) why do you need the scroll indicators?

Comment: the tableview is on a white background therefore it would be great to make clear to the user that he is able to scroll the table view because there are no visible border